# jQuery Ajax Post - Form data is not submitted correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this form

```
 <form method="post" name="addreply" id="addreply"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="pmid" id="pmid" value="">
                <textarea rows="10" cols="5" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Write your message..."></textarea>
                <input type="submit" class="butt green" value="Send">
              </form>
```

This is the jQuery code that is called when the form is submitted:

```
   $(function() {
        $('#addreply').submit(function(){

            $('#status').removeClass().addClass('alert info').html('Loading...').fadeIn();  

            $.post(
                '/index.php?i=pm&p=r', 
                $('form').serialize(),
                function (data) {
                    proccessData(data);
                }
            );
            return false;    
        });
    });
   function proccessData (data) {
        $('#status').hide().html('');

        if(data=='success'){
            $("#post").append('<li class="current-user"><img width="30" height="30" src="<?php echo $userdata['avatar'] ?>"><div class="bubble"><a class="user-name"><?php echo $userdata['username']; ?></a><p class="message">'+ $("#message").val() +'</p><p class="time"></p></div></li>');
            $('#message').val('');
        $(".widget-content").animate({ scrollTop: $('.widget-content')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000); 


        }
        else {
            $('#status').removeClass().addClass('alert error').html(data).fadeIn();
        }
    }
```

And this is the PHP code that is being posted:

```
   if($_POST)
    {
        $replyPrivateMessage = $privateMessage->replyMessage();
        switch($replyPrivateMessage)
        {

                case 1:
                    $error = 'The entered text is either too short or too long.';
                    $stop = true;
                break;
                case 2:
                    $error = 'Unexpected error.';
                    $stop = true;
                break;

                //If no error = success.    
                case 100:
                    die('success');
                break;
        }

        die($error);

    }
```

So the problem is that when I submit the form, I receive data "success"

Although, it just prints "success" using this:

```
   $('#status').removeClass().addClass('alert error').html(data).fadeIn();
```

Where it should be using:

```
if(data=='success'){
            $("#post").append('<li class="current-user"><img width="30" height="30" src="<?php echo $userdata['avatar'] ?>"><div class="bubble"><a class="user-name"><?php echo $userdata['username']; ?></a><p class="message">'+ $("#message").val() +'</p><p class="time"></p></div></li>');
            $('#message').val('');
        $(".widget-content").animate({ scrollTop: $('.widget-content')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000); 


        }
```

I can't seem to locate the issue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There's probably a trailing space somewhere, try trimming `data` then passing it.

Comment: @tymeJV where in the code should I add the trim function?

Comment: `processData($.trim(data));`

Comment: @tymeJV When I add that, it will submit the form like a normal form (not like AJAX without page refresh)

Comment: Why would that change how the form is submitted? It's simply trimming your callback data and passing it to the function, just like your code above.

Comment: I made a type. Now it just says that function processData is not defined

Comment: put in else condition `alert(data);` what becomes you?

Comment: Weird...this little added piece isn't changing any functionality of the code, why it would suddenly not find your function is..well weird

Comment: why don't you take a couple steps back and just try logging the data after you hit submit to your js console and see what it looks like.

Comment: @tymeJV Sorry about that! It worked with the trim(data). Thank you. Would you mind adding it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: show ur data... function (data) {
                    proccessData(data);
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to trim you data, it most likely has some trailing white spaces:

```
data = $.trim(data);
```

Or

```
 data = data.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

use ajax for this, it is very elegant method

```
$("#addreply").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            url:"abc.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                data=data.trim();
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                data=data.trim();
                alert(data);
            }
            });
});
```